# Browser plugin to resize window for brower testing

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, firefox-extensions, browser-plugin

When im making a website i work on my 22" external display, which is fine, but to get a better idea of what the site will look like on smaller screens i have to resize my browser window.

At the moment i use http://resizemybrowser.com/ (which also has a safari extension) but i was wandering if theres a firefox or chrome browser plugin that dose somthing similar, ive searched but so far been unable to find anything.

Comment: What tools are you using for web development?

Comment: sublime text and dreamwaver but i find myself leaning more toward sublime more and more of the time

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Was just digging around in firefox and found that it also has a "Responsive design" mode. Go to **Web Developer** → **Responsive Design View**.

[image]

You'll get a dropdown with preset resolutions afterwards:

[image]

Comment: Is there an api for this option ? Like for changing it from inside addon code?

Answer (score 3):

This is actually a built-in feature in Chrome.

1. Open the DevTools (<kbd>F12</kbd>)
2. Open the Settings

   [image]
3. Set the size you want for your window in the **Overrides** panel.

   [image]

Note: When selecting a User Agent in that panel, Chrome will automatically try to pick the correct device metrics for the selected agent.

Answer (score 2):

For Chrome you can use [Window Resizer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/window-resizer/kkelicaakdanhinjdeammmilcgefonfh?utm_source=chrome-ntp-icon). Fore Firefox, you can use [Firesizer](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/firesizer/).

Comment: Note that in December 2013 some [controversy](http://www.reddit.com/r/YouShouldKnow/comments/1snyyl/ysk_the_chrome_extension_called_window_resizer/) arose with this plugin after an update started redirecting Google searches through a third party